# Viewing and searching your libraries doxygen from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, doxygen

My question is rather simple. I have a project using a few external libraries documented with [`doxygen`](http://www.doxygen.org).

Is it possible, with Visual Studio (or with the help of an extension) to view to doc associated with a class or a method by clicking on it or via a keyboard shortcut, all without leaving Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled across [Doxygen Browser Add-in for Visual Studio](http://doxygenbrowseraddin.codeplex.com/), which looks quite good. Compatible with most currently used Visual Studio versions.

Other than that, there's a more DIY solution avaialble by (apparently quickly) writing up a Visual Studio extension, as [described here](http://innovativesolution.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/doxygen-intergration-in-visual-studio-environment/).

Comment: I checked this addin but it doesn't really work on VS2010. The browser part works so it shows a normal browser but the search function seems broken. Besides the project looks like it's not suported anymore. But thanks for trying, I upvote your answer anyway.